# Filtering out tuples nested in a list, removing specific values in certain indexes?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a problem where based on a chessboard (grid variable below) and a provided location of a rook, remove any elements from my grid variable (the chessboard) that contain the same x value or same y value as the rook (as rooks only move vertically and horizontally across the board).

```
#This portion of the code works correctly!    
#Generates the grid based on n provided to function
grid = [(x, y) for x in range(n) for y in range(n)]

#Say we use 4 as n
#Grid would be [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), #(2, 3), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Now the challenge comes when I try to filter out any tuples that the rook would be able to hit (same x value or same y value),

```
for x, y in rooks:
        #Isolate x and y value of the rook. In this test, let's use x = 2 and y = 3
        print(list(filter(lambda tuple: (x not in tuple, y not in tuple), grid)))
```

My challenge is when I try to specifically match the rook's x value against all the x values of the grid, I'm stuck with trying to incorporate this into my code. I know that to access all of my x values of the tuple, I need tuple[i][0] but don't know how to incorporate a quick snippet to cycle through all the tuples (i in the first element of tuple)

Within the filter() function, how many I able to have it rotate through all the tuples in the list (i variable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think list comprehensions are a snap for these type of things....

```
n = 4

grid = [(x, y) for x in range(n) for y in range(n)]

rock = (1, 2)

def reduced_grid(rock, grid):
    return [(x, y) for (x, y) in grid if x != rock[0] and y != rock[1]]


print(reduced_grid(rock, grid))

# [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: I think this tracks which squares the rook *can't* hit, rather than the squares the rook *can*.

Comment: Yeah, It wasn't 100% clear what the desired outcome was...  either the can's or can'ts..  Well, the alternative is only 2 exclamation points away!  :)

Comment: Yeah sorry! I should have specified, I am filtering out the ones that rooks cannot hit and returning the spaces on the board that are free from the rooks wrath

Answer (score 3):

Your issue with the filter function is that your lambda returns a `tuple` rather than a `boolean`, which will always be evaluated as true. You want your function to return all squares that have the same row or column as the rook, so your function should be:

```py
lambda tuple: x == tuple[0] or y == tuple[1]
```

Using your example:

```
>>> rooks = [[2, 3]]
>>> for x, y in rooks:
        print(list(filter(lambda tuple: x == tuple[0] or y == tuple[1], grid)))

[(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

(Also you probably shouldn't override the `tuple` variable, maybe use `square`?)

Comment: The above doesn't distinguish x & y coordinates...  which would likely be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

you can access the fields with a list comprehension by using the "tuple-parts" in a condition:

```
[field for field in grid if x == field[0] or y == field[1]]
```

gives you:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
```

Comment: ok, AirSquid was faster in presenting list comprehensions. This would be the other way round for having the accessible squares/fields